# Arch linux: unexpectedly shut down while installing a program

Tags: arch-linux, make, pacman

I was running `$ sudo pacman -S make` to install `make` utility.

During installation the power plug from my laptop was removed.

I tried boot system and it works.

I removed `make` files that I downloaded before and ran:

```
[awsyoos@arch ~]$ sudo pacman -S make
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (1) make-4.2.1-3

Total Installed Size:  1.49 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] Y
(1/1) checking keys in keyring                                                                                                         [##################################################################################] 100%
(1/1) checking package integrity                                                                                                       [##################################################################################] 100%
(1/1) loading package files                                                                                                            [##################################################################################] 100%
(1/1) checking for file conflicts                                                                                                      [##################################################################################] 100%
(1/1) checking available disk space                                                                                                    [##################################################################################] 100%
:: Processing package changes...
(1/1) installing make                                                                                                                  [##################################################################################] 100%
ldconfig: File /usr/lib/libatomic_ops_gpl.so.1.1.2 is empty, not checked.
ldconfig: File /usr/lib/libgccpp.so.1 is empty, not checked.
ldconfig: File /usr/lib/libguile-2.2.so.1.3.1 is empty, not checked.
ldconfig: File /usr/lib/libatomic_ops.so.1.1.1 is empty, not checked.
ldconfig: File /usr/lib/libgc.so.1 is empty, not checked.
ldconfig: File /usr/lib/libguile-2.2.so.1 is empty, not checked.
ldconfig: File /usr/lib/libgccpp.so.1.3.2 is empty, not checked.
ldconfig: File /usr/lib/libatomic_ops.so is empty, not checked.
ldconfig: File /usr/lib/libgc.so.1.3.4 is empty, not checked.
ldconfig: File /usr/lib/libgccpp.so is empty, not checked.
ldconfig: File /usr/lib/libatomic_ops_gpl.so is empty, not checked.
ldconfig: File /usr/lib/libcord.so is empty, not checked.
ldconfig: File /usr/lib/libcord.so.1.3.1 is empty, not checked.
ldconfig: File /usr/lib/libatomic_ops.so.1 is empty, not checked.
ldconfig: File /usr/lib/libatomic_ops_gpl.so.1 is empty, not checked.
ldconfig: File /usr/lib/libguile-2.2.so is empty, not checked.
ldconfig: File /usr/lib/libgc.so is empty, not checked.
ldconfig: File /usr/lib/libcord.so.1 is empty, not checked.
:: Running post-transaction hooks...
(1/2) Arming ConditionNeedsUpdate...
(2/2) Updating the info directory file...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do:

```
sudo pacman -S make --overwrite
```